# Finding when data at a particular memory location was last modified? (C, gcc, gdb, valgrid, clang?)

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, memory, segmentation-fault

I have a nasty segfault that's been plaguing me for a while. It had something to do with migration of code from 32-bit to 64-bit, but it's an occasional fault and hard to track down.

I wanted to know -- is there any tool (pref. Linux, FOSS) that I can use to trace back from a segfault, to find where in my code an illegal (out-of-bounds) pointer was assigned its value?

For example, if I get a segfault by trying to read the `int` value pointed to by my variable `int *a` (the value of which has been assigned somewhere else somewhere far away in my code), how can I find *where* in the code that value was assigned?

It seems like the sort of thing one might be able to do with clang/llvm, but I don't really know where to look. I guess such a think can't really be done with gdb or valgrind, because IFAIK they don't have a way to store the required information during program execution.

Any suggestions anyone has got would be much appreciated!

***Edit:*** after much digging, I found the error I had been looking for. Basically, a 'unsigned long *' was being cast to 'int *' in such a way that warnings were suppressed, somehow (http://ascend4.org/b564). The question still stands, though, because my bug-search was very manual and tedious: **if I have a variable in my program, how I can trace back to find what sequence/chain/tree of statements caused it to take its current value?** Is there *any* tool that automates this? This includes passing of parameters to functions, assignment statements (including assignment via dereferenced pointer), etc.

Comment: You could try replacing `malloc` with `mmap` in a way that leaves either the bytes before the beginning or after the end of the array unmapped. But why doesn't valgrind work? I think valgrind should be the tool for problems like this.

Comment: there is a backtrace for gdb : http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html.

Comment: @juhist: I don't think that replacement malloc doesn't the trick. It's not so much a question of accessing previously-freed memory, finding where unallocated memory is accessed, or anything like that. What I need is something that helps me to track down *where* a dodgy pointer was created/calculated. In other words, what is the dependency-graph of operations that have led to a particular pointer having the value that it currently has? FWIW tried http://dmalloc.com/, similar to what you are mentioning, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

A memory breakpoint (watchpoint in the GDB docs) sounds like the way to go. Compile using `-g` for debugging symbols and then place a memory-write breakpoint like this:

```
print &a
watch *0xdeadbeef
```

If you want to include the reads too, you can use `awatch`. Check the [GDB docs for more information](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).
That way you should be able to trace the last write before the segmentation fault occurs.

Comment: I'll do a bit of investigating with the approach. I guess what I was hoping for was something a bit like a stack trace, except for showing me what code was involved in creating the invalid pointer that eventually triggered the segfault. Such a thing could be automatic, potentially, with the right kind of clever debugging tool...

Comment: On further investigation, I don't think the approach of watching a particular memory location is quite right either. Because the memory location containing the invalid pointer was in the stack (a passed-in parameter), adding a memory watch just results in lots of breaks when that same memory is used for other purposes. If it had been on the heap (malloc'ed etc), it would have helped.

Answer (score 1):

The tool you should be using for problems like this is `valgrind`. For example, try the following code with Valgrind:

```
char *str = malloc(10);
str[10] = '\0';
```

It prints:

```
==14272== Invalid write of size 1
==14272==    at 0x80483E4: main (in /path/to/a.out)
==14272==  Address 0x4025032 is 0 bytes after a block of size 10 alloc'd
==14272==    at 0x4005BDC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==14272==    by 0x80483D8: main (in /path/to/a.out)
```

However, if `valgrind` is not working for you, an option would be to replace `malloc` with `mmap` in a way that leaves either the bytes before the beginning of the allocated block or the bytes after the end of the allocated block unmapped. Because block sizes in general are not multiples of page sizes, you can pick only one of the options, not both. But you can run your problem with the "leave beginning unmapped" and "leave end unmapped" strategies separately to catch both kinds of errors.

The code for how to replace `malloc` with `mmap` is too long for this answer, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think that valgrind helps in this case, because the problem isn't with allocating/reading/freeing memory (well, it's reading, but I'm reading from somewhere that I didn't mean to... why?). The problem is in identifying what particular bit of pointer arithmetic, variable mis-assignment, etc, led to my incorrect pointer. And given that my problem only occurs on 64-bit systems, it seems like it probably coming from that pointer being passed through a 32-bit integer cast, or something like that. I don't see how valgrind will help me track that down.

Comment: Referring to your example with str[10]='\n', my probably is essentially that the "10" is probably a variable, and I want to know where the value of "10" is coming from. It's been calculated from somewhere... but where? It should be possible to trace something like that.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question then. The memory breakpoint approach may help, or it may be the case that it isn't of any help.